# Firewall traffic routing when visiting a specific website

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, traffic, sonicwall

I've got an odd question/request, here's what it is.

We have a block of 5 public static IP addresses and there's a website that they are requesting that we try and set up so that when we visit it it doesn't come from our primary IP address that all other traffic comes from, but instead it come from a different address.

So normal traffic comes from x.x.x.24 let's say but
We visit x website traffic comes from x.x.x.25

Can this be accomplished via Sonicwall?  I'm not sure the method to achieve this.

Thanks in advance if you help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the website's IP address, I don't know sonicwall specifics but you'd need to add a NAT rule before the global NAT rule like this

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -s internal_network/internal_network_mask -d website_address --to-source x.x.x.25
```

internal_network should be something like 192.168.1.0/24
internal_network_mask should be something like 255.255.255.0

This of course assuming your firewall is configured to receive traffic back on x.x.x.25 via a subinterface, secondary IP address of PROXY ARP